# What does org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-timeout mean?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

I am using a linux OS which uses `bluez v5.64` and `alsa`. Whenever I try to connect to my bluetooth earphones, I get the following error:-

```
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-timeout
```

Complete `bluetoothctl` log:-

```
$ bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent 
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# power on 
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller C4:46:19:F8:6D:08 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 boAt Rockerz
[bluetooth]# pair 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 
Attempting to pair with 11:11:22:CC:94:F4
[CHG] Device 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# trust 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 
[CHG] Device 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 Trusted: yes
Changing 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# connect 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 
Attempting to connect to 11:11:22:CC:94:F4
[CHG] Device 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 RSSI: -63
[CHG] Device 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 ServicesResolved: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-timeout
[CHG] Device 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 11:11:22:CC:94:F4 RSSI: -53
[bluetooth]#
```

It happens even when I try to connect to my other earphones.

So, my questions are:-

- What does this error mean?
- How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.